# Can you use a while loop inside a case in switch statement in C?

Tags: c, loops, switch-statement, case

This might be a **really** stupid question, and if it is, please excuse me for it, but I have been looking for an answer before and I haven't found anything. Is it possible to write something like

```
case 'i':
    do
    {
        root=insert(root,code[1]);
        scanf("%s",code);
    }while (code[0]=='i');
    break;
```

in C? Thank you for your answer and sorry again if this is a stupid question. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Yes you can, switches are just glorified goto labels

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: You can find this by trying it actually!!

Comment: Sure,  you can.  Have you already tried?

Comment: I tried, the reason I'm asking this question is because my code was working with more if statements and as soon as I edited it and used the switch statement, it stopped working. I was just wondering if that would have been the problem, but it's clearly not. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, though for anything other than very short loops it can rapidly make your code unreadable.

In such cases it's better to put the loop into a function and call it from the case. That's short, succinct, and easily maintained.

Another I find worth doing is

```
switch (ch)
{
   case 'i':
   {
      // do stuff
      MainLoop();
      break;
   } 
}
```

Simply because it keeps the curly braces all neat and tidy though that's probably going to annoy a lot of people!

Answer (score 1):

If it is necessary for your project, then you can use it.
There is no harm in using it. Compiler wouldn't throw any error or warning.
It will work as expected if created with care.

But it could make your code unreadable and also it will increase the level of indentation.

You can create a function which will have your loop. It could increase readability of the code.

For example,

```
case 'i':
        func();
        break;
```